# How to "normalize" an URL replacing any special characters with new ones

Tags: iphone, url, nsstring, ascii, special-characters

In any URL, you can have special characters like **? & ~ : / **

and soon if not already, **accentuated characters**

What I'd like is to convert ANY url into it's nearest equivalent in pure ASCII character
THEN replacing any remaining spécial charaters by a _

I've tried this looking and inspiring myslef with many examples over the net, but it do not work (for example, using this code, the character "é" is not converted to "e" in  `@"http://www.mélange.fr/~fermer.php?aa=10&ee=13"`)

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *charactersToKeep = [NSMutableCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
[charactersToKeep addCharactersInString:@"://&=~?"];
NSCharacterSet* charactersToRemove = [charactersToKeep invertedSet];
myNSString = [[[myNSString decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

to start, after I will have to convert remaining special characters with _
```

How may I achieve this ?

As an example (and only for example), I'd like to convert :

```
http://www.mélange.fr/~fermer.php?aa=10&ee=13
```

to

```
http___www.melange.fr__fermer_php_aa_10_ee_13
```

of course **without having to check one by one each possible special or accentued character**.

Comment: What do you mean by "is does not work"? Can you give an example of an input string and the expected and actual output?

Comment: wouldn't these non-ASCII characters be the kind of thing that would be encoded via something like NSString's "`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                        NSASCIIStringEncoding];`

Comment: @MartinR:I give the example in the question. I move it to make it more visible, and I add one at the bottom to be more explicit

Comment: Rob's answer looks quite good to me, it definitely transforms `é` into `e`. Did you try that?

Comment: @Rob:Sorry, it's a mistake :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. To replace accented characters with unaccented ones, there are a couple of candidates:

   - You can use [`CFStringTransform`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001504-CH201-BCIGCACA):

     ```
     NSMutableString *mutableString = [string mutableCopy];
     CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)mutableString, NULL, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, NO);
     ```
   - You could use [`dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-dataUsingEncoding_allowLossyConversion_)

     ```
     NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
     NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     ```

     Characters it doesn't know what to do with become `?` and but this sometimes replaces one character with multiple characters (e.g. `©` with `(C)`), which you may or may not want.
2. Once you do this international character conversion, it looks like you want replace any non-alphanumeric character (or period) with an underscore, which you could do with a [`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3aoptions%3arange%3a) with a regular expression:

   ```
       NSString *result = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^a-z0-9\\.]"
                                                            withString:@"_"
                                                               options:NSRegularExpressionSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
   ```

   There are lots of permutations of this regular expression that will accomplish the same thing, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I'm talking about the whole URL

Comment: Thank you. This works, and works fine for the example, but I'd like to master the characters that are converted instead of counting on luck. Would you have, keeping this solution in mind, an alternative that would allow that ? This was the reason I was seduced by the NSMutableCharacterSet way of doing.

Comment: The reason of my asking is to master how a special caracter may be encoded at the end. I mean, © is converted in (c)... but what if I don't want to convert it to ensure it won't enlarge my string. And what if the conversion method evolves in the future and do not give (c) but just c. I won't be able to rollback my converted strings without being able to reproduce the way of doing of the method. So I wanted to make a conversion that just unnaccents "natural" accentuated charater, without touching any others, that I would have underscored later. So my string keeps its size. Is it possible ?

Comment: Life is hard :-)  Thank you for your help

Comment: @Oliver By the way, I stumbled across `CFStringTransform`, which can also replace your accented characters; and you can use regex to replace the rest of the non-alphanumeric characters with underscores. See revised answer.